# Adding measurement errors to pymc model

Tags: pymc

I have the following model in pymc2:

```
import pymc
from scipy.stats import gamma

alpha = pymc.Uniform('alpha', 0.01, 2.0)
scale = pymc.Uniform('scale', 1.0, 4.0)

@pymc.deterministic(plot=False)
def beta(scale=scale):
    return 1.0 / scale

@pymc.potential
def p_factor(alpha=alpha, scale=scale, lmin=lmin, n=len(sample)):
    dist = gamma(alpha, loc=0., scale=scale)
    fp = 1.0 - dist.cdf(lmin)
    return -(n+1)*np.log(fp)

obs = pymc.Gamma("obs", alpha=alpha, beta=beta, value=sample, observed=True)
```

The physical background of this model is the [luminosity function of galaxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_function_%28astronomy%29) (LF), i.e., the probability of a galaxy having luminosity L. For some types of galaxies, the LF is just a gamma function. The potential accounts for data truncation, as galaxy surveys usually miss a substantial fraction of the targets, particularly those of low luminosity. In this model I miss everything below `lmin`

Details of this method can be found in [this paper by Kelly et al](http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.2946).

This model works: I run `MAP` and `MCMC` on the model and I can recover the parameters `alpha` and `scale` from my simulated data `sample`, with increased uncertainty as `lmin` grows.

Now I would like to insert gaussian measurement errors. For simplicity all the data has the same precision. I'm not modifying the potential to include the errors also.

```
alpha = pymc.Uniform('alpha', 0.01, 2.0)
scale = pymc.Uniform('scale',1.0, 4.0)
sig = 0.1
tau = math.pow(sig, -2.0)  

@pymc.deterministic(plot=False)
def beta(scale=scale):
    return 1.0 / scale

@pymc.potential
def p_factor(alpha=alpha, scale=scale, lmin=lmin, n=len(sample)):
    dist = gamma(alpha, loc=0., scale=scale)
    fp = 1.0 - dist.cdf(lmin)
    return -(n+1) * np.log(fp)

dist = pymc.Gamma("dist", alpha=alpha, beta=beta)
obs = pymc.Normal("obs", mu=dist, tau=tau, value=sample, observed=True)
```

But surely I'm doing something wrong here because this model does not work.
When I run `pymc.MAP`on this model I recover the initial values of `alpha` and `scale`

```
vals = {'alpha': alpha, 'scale': scale, 'beta': beta, 
   'p_factor': p_factor, 'obs': obs, 'dist': dist}
M2 = pymc.MAP(vals)
M2.fit()
print M2.alpha.value, M2.scale.value
>>> (array(0.010000000006018368), array(1.000000000833973))
```

When I run `pymc.MCMC`, `alpha` and `beta` are no traced at all.

```
M = pymc.MCMC(vals)
M.sample(10000, burn=5000)
...
M.stats()['alpha']
>>> {'95% HPD interval': array([ 0.01000001,  0.01000502]),
'mc error': 2.1442678276712383e-07,
'mean': 0.010001588137798096,
'n': 5000,
'quantiles': {2.5: 0.0100000088679046,
25: 0.010000382359859467,
50: 0.010001100377476166,
75: 0.010001668672799679,
97.5: 0.0100050194240779},
'standard deviation': 2.189828287191421e-06}
```

again initial values. In fact if I change `alpha` to start in, say, 0.02, the recovered values of `alpha` is 0.02.

This is [a notebook with the working model plus simulated data](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/guaix.fis.ucm.es/~spr/notebooks/lumfunc/recover%20N1.ipynb?create=1).

This is [a notebook with the error model plus simulated data](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/guaix.fis.ucm.es/~spr/notebooks/lumfunc/Recover%20N%20with%20errors.ipynb?create=1).

Any guidance on making this work would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is enough to change

```
dist = pymc.Gamma("dist", alpha=alpha, beta=beta)
```

by

```
dist = pymc.Gamma("dist", alpha=alpha, beta=beta, value=sample)
```

The sampled data is a reasonable initial value for `dist`. Anyway, I do no get the logic, as other initial values (such as an array of zeros) bring back the problem of not sampling `alpha` and `beta` again.